# problema de logica al instanciar clase Javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy comenzando con **Javascript y POO**, pero al crear esta clase y escribir el comando para imprimir en consola, solo me muestra el contenido del objeto:

```
(ƒ operacion(){
    return this.n1+this.n2;
})
```

Que es lo que impide que no reciba los números que ingreso al constructor y me imprima el resultado?
Gracias! :D
Código;

```
class sumatoria{
    numero (n1,n2){
        this.n1=n1;
        this.n2=n2;
    }

    get resultado(){
        return this.operacion
    }

    operacion(){
        return this.n1+this.n2;
    }
}

var suma= new sumatoria(2+2);
console.log(suma.resultado);
```

Comment: porque es `console.log(suma.resultado());`

Comment: Tu clase no tiene un constructor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hice algunos cambios:

1. Una clase tiene que tener un constructor.
2. `console.log(suma.resultado());`en lugar de  `console.log(suma.resultado);` ya que resultado es un método.

```js
class sumatoria{
    constructor (n1,n2){
        this.n1=n1;
        this.n2=n2;
    }

    get resultado(){
        return this.operacion
    }

    operacion(){
        return this.n1+this.n2;
    }
}

var suma= new sumatoria(2,2);
console.log(suma.resultado());
```